# Solution verification for an equation of exponentially distributed random variables

Tags: distributions, exponential-distribution, checking

Given two i.i.d. random variables $X,Y$, such that $X\sim \exp(1),  Y \sim \exp(1)$. I am looking for the probability $\Phi$. However, the analytical solution that I have got does not match with my simulation. I am presenting it here with the hope that someone with rectifies my mistake.

$$\Phi =\mathbb{P}\left[P_v \geq A + \frac{B}{Y}\right] $$

$$
P_v=
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
 a\left(\frac{b}{1+\exp\left(-\bar \mu\frac{P_s X}{r^\alpha}+\varphi\right)}-1\right), & \text{if}\ \frac{P_s X}{r^\alpha}\geq P_a,\\
0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{array}
\right.
$$

---

**My solution**

\begin{multline}
  \Phi = \mathbb{P}\left[ a\left(\frac{b}{1+\exp\left(-\bar \mu\frac{P_s X}{r^\alpha}+\varphi\right)}-1\right) \geq A  +  \frac{B}{Y}\right]\mathbb{P}\left[X \geq \frac{P_ar^\alpha}{P_s}\right] + {\mathbb{P}\left[0 \geq A + \frac{B}{Y}\right] \mathbb{P}\left[X \geq \frac{P_ar^\alpha}{P_s}\right]} 
\end{multline}

Given that $\mathbb{P}[0>A+\frac{B}{Y}] = 0$

$$ \Phi = \mathbb{P}\left[a\left(\frac{b}{1+\exp\left(-\bar \mu\frac{P_s X}{r^\alpha}+\varphi\right)}-1\right) \geq A + \frac{B}{Y}\right] \exp\left(-\frac{P_ar^\alpha}{P_s}\right) $$

Now consider only the first part of the expression on the right side of the equation, and letting $c = \frac{\bar{\mu}P_s}{r^{\alpha}}$.

$$ \mathbb{P}\left[a\left(\frac{b}{1+\exp\left(-\bar \mu\frac{P_s X}{r^\alpha}+\varphi\right)}-1\right) \geq A + \frac{B}{Y}\right] = \mathbb{P}\left[\frac{ab}{1+\exp\left(-c X+\varphi\right)}-a \geq A + \frac{B}{Y}\right]$$

consider $D = A + a$, with mathematical manipulations and using the fact that $\mathbb{E}[Y] = \frac{1}{\lambda} = 1$ and $\mathbb{E}[e^{-sX}] = \frac{1}{1+s}$, we get:

$$ \Phi = \mathbb{P} \left[Y \geq \frac{1}{ab}\mathbb{E}_Y[DY + B]. \mathbb{E}_X [1+e^\varphi e^{-c X}] \right]  $$

$$\Phi = \exp\left(-\frac{D+B}{ab}\left(1 + \frac{e^\varphi}{1+c}\right)\right)\exp\left(-\frac{P_a r^\alpha}{P_s}\right) $$

[image: Plot for simulation and mathematical analysis]

Comment: How did you reach from second to third equation?

Comment: Simultaneously posted at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/237037/how-to-solve-following-equation-with-multiple-random-variables.

Comment: "distance" in your figure is what function of the parameters?

Comment: Distance $r$ is with the parameter $c$ and the second exponential in the equation. See $\exp(-\frac{P_a r^alpha}{P_s})$. I posted it simultaneously for better as it has Mathematica as well as arithmetic aspects.

Comment: I don't have any problems with posting things simultaneously.  However, when you don't mention that, the answer might appear on one forum and the experts on the other forum would then be wasting their time on a problem that is already solved.  (Or on one forum a comment might trigger a complete answer on the other forum.)

Comment: Got your point.